# Why this query (returning forecasts into a time range) return an empty result set when the month change?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and I have the following problem with this query that extracts some records from a table. I am using **MySql**.

I have a main table named **MeteoForecast** that contains meteo forecast like these:

```
INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (17, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/11/27 06:00:00.000', '2017/11/27 12:00:00.000', 27, 33, 'Light_Rain.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (18, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/11/27 12:00:00.000', '2017/11/27 18:00:00.000', 35, 29, 'Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (19, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/11/28 06:00:00.000', '2017/11/28 12:00:00.000', 26, 31, 'Light_Rain.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (20, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/11/28 12:00:00.000', '2017/11/28 18:00:00.000', 33, 27, 'Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (21, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/10/13 12:00:00.000', '2017/10/13 18:00:00.000', 18, 22, 'Light_Rain.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (22, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/11/29 06:00:00.000', '2017/11/29 12:00:00.000', 30, 34, 'Light_Rain.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (23, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/11/29 12:00:00.000', '2017/11/29 18:00:00.000', 34, 31, 'Light_Rain.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (24, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/11/30 06:00:00.000', '2017/11/30 12:00:00.000', 29, 32, 'Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (25, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/11/30 12:00:00.000', '2017/11/30 18:00:00.000', 33, 31, 'Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (26, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/12/01 06:00:00.000', '2017/12/01 12:00:00.000', 27, 31, 'Light_Rain.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (27, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/12/01 12:00:00.000', '2017/12/01 18:00:00.000', 34, 29, 'Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (28, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/12/02 06:00:00.000', '2017/12/02 12:00:00.000', 28, 34, 'Light_Rain.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (29, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/12/02 12:00:00.000', '2017/12/02 18:00:00.000', 34, 31, 'Light_Rain.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (30, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/12/03 06:00:00.000', '2017/12/03 12:00:00.000', 26, 29, 'Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (31, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/12/03 12:00:00.000', '2017/12/03 18:00:00.000', 29, 33, 'Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (32, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/12/04 06:00:00.000', '2017/12/04 12:00:00.000', 25, 29, 'Mostly_Cloudy_Icon.png');

INSERT INTO MeteoForecast (id, localization_id, seasonal_forecast_id, meteo_warning_id, start_date, end_date, min_temp, max_temp, icon_link) VALUES (33, 1, NULL, NULL, '2017/12/04 12:00:00.000', '2017/12/04 18:00:00.000', 30, 33, 'Light_Rain.png');
```

As you can see these records start with the **start_date** field having value in the November and end with the **start_date** field having value in December.

Now I have this query that extract the records related to the forecasts of the next 7 days starting from today:

```
SELECT
          DATE_FORMAT(MF.start_date, GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'ISO')) AS start_date                           ,
          MF.id                                                  AS meteo_forecast_id                    ,
          MF.min_temp                                            AS min_temp                             ,
          MF.max_temp                                            AS max_temp                             ,
          MF.icon_link                                           AS icon_link                            ,
          MFD.id                                                 AS meteo_forecast_description_id        ,
          MFD.meteo_forecast_description_name                    AS meteo_forecast_description_name      ,
          MFD.description                                        AS meteo_forecast_description           ,
          MFD.audio_link                                         AS meteo_forecast_description_audio_link,
          MA.id                                                  AS meteo_advice_id                      ,
          MA.description                                         AS meteo_advice_description             ,
          CR.id                                                  AS crop_id                              ,
          CR.crop_name                                           AS crop_name                            ,
          MA.planting_date                                       AS planting_date                        ,
          MA.harvesting_date                                     AS harvesting_date                      ,
          MA.water_needs                                         AS water_needs                          ,
          MA.audiolink                                           AS meteo_advice_audiolink
FROM
          MeteoForecast as MF
          LEFT JOIN
                    MeteoForecast_MeteoForecastDescription as MF_MFD
                    ON
                              MF.id = MF_MFD.meteo_forecast_id
          LEFT JOIN
                    MeteoForecastDescription as MFD
                    ON
                              MF_MFD.meteo_forecast_description_id = MFD.id
          LEFT JOIN
                    Languages AS LNG
                    ON
                              MFD.language_id = LNG.id
                              AND LNG.id      = 1
          LEFT JOIN
                    MeteoAdvice AS MA
                    ON
                              MF.id = MA.meteo_forecast_id
          LEFT JOIN
                    Crop AS CR
                    ON
                              MA.crop_id = CR.id
WHERE
          MF.localization_id = 1
          AND MF.start_date >= CURDATE()
          AND MF.end_date   <= CURDATE()+7
ORDER BY
          MF.start_date
```

As you can see in the **WHERE** condition I have these 2 clauses specifying the time range (from today to the next 7 days):

```
AND MF.start_date >= CURDATE()
AND MF.end_date   <= CURDATE()+7
```

And here the big problem: in this way I obtain an empty resultset, no output records are returned by my query.

Should exist a bug (in my query) related when the month change from November to December because if I change the second condition in this way:

```
AND MF.end_date   <= CURDATE()+4
```

it works and correctly retrieve the records related to the the last day of November (today **CURDATE()+4**).

So what could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I try to fix it?

**EDIT-1:** Additional information.

I am trying to print the value returned by the **curdate()** function putting it into the SELECT statment by:

```
CURDATE() AS cur_date,
```

and it return something like this: **27/11/2017** but if I try to change it in this way (adding the days):

```
CURDATE() + 4 AS cur_date,
```

the value is no more a standard date but it is something like this: **20171131**.

So maybe there is something wrong when it now try to evaluate this expression:

```
AND MF.end_date   <= CURDATE()+4
```

What can I try to do to solve this issue?

Comment: Since scrolling code is needed, I'd recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself, changing the second WHERE clauses with this code:

```
AND MF.end_date   <=  ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 7)
```